# Django: Make pagination's urls SEO friendly

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm trying to make my pagination url's from `django` a little bit SEO friendly. Instead of `?page=current_page` something of the form `/page/current_page`.

So in my `app/urls.py` I did the following:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/page/(?P<page>[0-9])+$', GalleryDetail.as_view(), name='galleries-view-gallery-paginator')
```

and on my `app/templates/app/my_view.html`:

```
{% if page_obj.has_next %}       
  <a href="{% url 'galleries-view-gallery-paginator' page_obj.next_page_number %}">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

But I get a `NoReverseMatch` **error**.

Other error info: `Reverse for 'galleries-view-gallery-paginator' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['gallery/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/page/(?P<page>[0-9])+$']`

And well. How can I achieve urls like `/page/current_page` using `Django`?

Comment: Sighhh! it works now! thank you a lot @ozgur . If you post an answer I'll accepted it! :-)

Comment: @ozgur the slug value = gallery.slug if that's what you mean. I solved it with just: `{% url 'galleries-view-gallery-paginator' gallery.slug page_obj.next_page_number %}` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL `galleries-view-gallery-paginator` requires you to pass 2 parameters: `slug` and `page`. Since you are passing only the page number, slug is also needed:

```
{% url 'galleries-view-gallery-paginator' gallery.slug page_obj.next_page_number %}
```